# Как сравнить данные

Tags: python

Имеем:

```py
data={'phone':'950895778','code':"'1234'} и bonuses={'950895778':{'1234':'12000'}]
```

Теперь вопрос:
Как сравнить этих данных и если `phone` и `code` совпадут вывести в бот значение `'12000'`.

Comment: Возвращает требуемое значение или `None`: `bonuses.get(data['phone'], {}).get(data['code'])`.

Answer (score 1):

может так вас устроит? функция `f` возращает нужное либо None. То есть вызываете функцию `f` если возвращаемое значение не None то вывод его в бот (про это я ничего не знаю)

```
data={'phone':'950895778','code':'1234'}
bonuses={'950895778':{'1234':'12000'}}
def f(data, bonuses):
    if(data['phone'] in bonuses.keys() and data['code'] in bonuses[data['phone']].keys()):
        return bonuses[data['phone']][data['code']];
print(f(data,bonuses))
```

Comment: `in bonuses.keys()` -> `in bonuses`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Данные
data = {'phone': '950895778', 'code': '1234'}
bonuses = {'950895778': {'1234': '12000'}}

# Проверяем, имеется ли такой номер телефона в данных о бонусах и если имеется,
# то проверяем, имеется ли с тем кодом, который в объекте data
bonus = bonuses.get(data['phone'])
if bonus is not None and bonus.get(data['code']) is not None:
    # Если всё совпадает, то то выведется нужный код
    print(bonus.get(data['code']))
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, все работает исправно.